# Sort Column Based on Another Column Order

Tags: excel, vba

i have two columns A and B and i want to sort A based on the order of B values. and i want to do this VBA

```
 *11000000      11750020
 11020150       11050010
 11000002       11520090

 i want this result;
 11750020       11750020
 11050010       11050010
 11520090       11520090
 *

enter code here
Dim SortByCol As Range
Dim ToSortCol As Range
Set SortByCol = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("B")
Set ToSortCol = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("A")

Dim SortRange As Range
Set SortRange = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1")
Union(SortByCol, ToSortCol).Copy SortRange
Set SortRange = SortRange.CurrentRegion
With SortRange.Parent.Sort

    .SortFields.Add Key:=SortRange.Range("A" & SortRange.Rows.Count), 
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange SortRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = True
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom:
    '.SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

SortRange.Columns(2).Copy ToSortCol

SortRange.Clear
```

Comment: I think you should keep the code you originally posted in your question. It'll show what you have tried so far. Otherwise this question might get closed as too broad.

Comment: View the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681952/custom-sorting-with-custom-ordering)