# Sort Data to Match Order of A List Column - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have list from a client that I used to retrieve more data from our internal system. The clients data doesn't have any discernable sort pattern. The data I retrieved is sorted. I would basically like to sort the entire data retrieval section based on the client list original order now that I have confirmed my data pull is complete.

I'm unsure how to even begin this process and wondered if there was an excel function/vba function (prefer VBA) that would accomplish this or if I am going to have to do some insane looping to move data around.

Example Data:

Client List:

```
IDs
Z594153
A594157
Y594167
```

My List:

```
IDs     Data
A594157 R
Y594167 B
Z594153 M
```

Desired Output:

```
IDs     Data
Z594153 M
A594157 R
Y594167 B
```

How can I sort "My List" back to the original "Client List". I'm picturing placing the client list on the same worksheet, separated by one blank column and somehow using that as a helper column, or perhaps it would be better to have the client list on a separate worksheet as I want to sort entire rows from my data retrieval based on a single column from client list which is also present in my data retrieval list.

Sorry I don't have much code yet as I'm unsure best way to proceed.

Comment: Using a helper column is the simplest solution. If you're using VBA, you can assign the same helper number as a unique ID that can be sorted later. It all depends if you can use a helper column directly on the worksheet.

Comment: You could just do a simple `Index/Match` formula for it. As in: `INDEX(YourDataRange,MATCH(ClientID,YourIDRange,0))` and pull it down beside the client list.

Comment: You can specify custom sort orders in Excel and apply to a new range. Use macro recorder to record this and adjust. Don't know what the limits are on this and whether you can use dynamic named range as source.

Comment: [Custom Sort Lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-cba3d67a-c5cb-406f-9b14-a02205834d72) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Custom Sort Lists are almost easier to use in the GUI vs VBA. There are a few things I want to note before I move on.

There is a twist between .Cells.Sort.SortFields.Add and .Cells.Sort that usually generates some confusion. The .SortFields.Add method uses a CustomOrder:= parameter and the Range.Sort method uses a OrderCustom:= parameter. The two are most definitely NOT the same but often get used interchangeably with disastrous results.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682618/5079799

I found that I could not get `OrderCustom` to work as it always sorted either via `xlAscending/Descending` which the whole point of this exercise is I want to sort my output in a non alphanumerical way. (But this would be my preferred way, and reference the Custom List via it's "integer value")

I also spent a lot of time reading this article, which teaches about creating/saving/finding/delete Custom Order lists. But, I couldn't actually find a way to use a list I "created".

https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-for-customlists-autofill-lists/

In the end I just used a simple "For Loop" to generate a String from each cells value in the "Custom Column" in the format of "One,Two,Three" and fed that to `CustomOrder:=CVar(CustomOrderStr)` make sure to use `CVar`!

Here is the code, note lots of this isn't needed, but I left it all for posterity:

**Functions:**

```
Public Function CustomOrderStrFromRng(rng As Range) As String
'Generate String for "CustomOrder:="Str1,Str2"
 For Each rcell In rng.Cells
  CustomOrderStrFromRng = CustomOrderStrFromRng & rcell.Value & ","
 Next rcell
 CustomOrderStrFromRng = Left(CustomOrderStrFromRng, Len(CustomOrderStrFromRng) - 1)
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function CustomListFromRange(rng As Range) As Integer
'Either Create or Return Int Value for Custom List
 Dim CustomListArr As Variant
 CustomListArr = RangeToArray(rng)
 On Error Resume Next
  Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array(CustomListArr)
 On Error GoTo 0
 CustomListFromRange = Application.GetCustomListNum(Array(CustomListArr))
 Debug.Print "Custom List Int = " & CustomListFromRange
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function NumberOfCustomLists() As Integer
 NumberOfCustomLists = Application.CustomListCount
 Debug.Print "NumberOfCustomLists = " & NumberOfCustomLists
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub DelCustomList(ListInt As Integer)
 Application.DeleteCustomList listNum:=ListInt
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function lRowOfCol(Optional ByVal ColNum As Long, Optional ByVal ColLet As String, Optional ByVal Endxl As String) As Long
    If StrComp(Endxl, "DOWN", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
     If ColNum > 0 Then
      lRowOfCol = Cells(1, ColNum).End(xlDown).Row
     Else
      lRowOfCol = Range(ColLet & "1").End(xlDown).Row
     End If
    Else
     If ColNum > 0 Then
      lRowOfCol = Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
     Else
      lRowOfCol = Range(ColLet & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     End If
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function RangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        arr(i) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
     Next r

    RangeToArray = arr
End Function
```

---

**Subs:**

```
Public Sub CustomSortDataFromColumn(DataRng As Range, CustomListColStr As String, KeyColStr As String)

Dim CustomListCol As Range, CustomListCollRow As Integer, CustomListColInt As Integer
Dim KeyCol As Range, KeyCollRow As Integer, KeyColInt As Integer

CustomListColInt = Columns(CustomListColStr).Column
CustomListCollRow = lRowOfCol(CustomListColInt)
Set CustomListCol = Range(Cells(2, CustomListColInt), Cells(CustomListCollRow, CustomListColInt))

KeyColInt = Columns(KeyColStr).Column
KeyCollRow = lRowOfCol(KeyColInt)
Set KeyCol = Range(Cells(2, KeyColInt), Cells(KeyCollRow, KeyColInt))

Dim CustomOrderStr As String
CustomOrderStr = CustomOrderStrFromRng(CustomListCol)

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=KeyCol, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=CVar(CustomOrderStr)
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange DataRng
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Test_CustomSortDataFromColumn()
 
 Dim DataRng As Range, CustomListCol As String, KeyCol As String
 Set DataRng = Range("A1:G70")
 CustomListCol = "I"
 KeyCol = "E"

 Call CustomSortDataFromColumn(DataRng, CustomListCol, KeyCol)

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub TestingCustomLists()

 Dim NoOfLists As Integer
 NoOfLists = NumberOfCustomLists()

 Dim CusListRng As Range, CusListInt As Integer
 Set CusListRng = Range("I2:I70")

 CusListInt = CustomListFromRange(CusListRng)
 Debug.Print "CusListInt = " & CusListInt

 NoOfLists = NumberOfCustomLists()

 Call DelCustomList(CusListInt)

 NoOfLists = NumberOfCustomLists()

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub SortRangeByCustomList()

 Dim DataRng As Range, CustomListCol As Range, KeyCol As Range
 Set DataRng = Range("A1:G70")
 Set CustomListCol = Range("I2:I70")
 Set KeyCol = Range("E2:E70")

 Dim CustomOrderStr As String
 CustomOrderStr = CustomOrderStrFromRng(CustomListCol)

 ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=KeyCol, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=CVar(CustomOrderStr)
 With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SetRange DataRng
     .Header = xlYes
     .MatchCase = False
     .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
     .SortMethod = xlPinYin
     .Apply
 End With

End Sub
```

Next step will be a UserForm + IRibbonControl, but that's enough for this post!

Comment: I would read in to an array and use Join$ with delim rather than cell looping and in fact macro recording shows I can do _Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")'_ so I could assign a transposed array directly with Join$; then looks like some of the other bits involve _CustomOrder:= "A,B,C,D,E", DataOption:=xlSortNormal_

Comment: The trick for me wasn't creating the custom list, but calling it. What goes after `CustomOrder:=` IE< how to use a variable vs you have `CustomOrder:= "A,B,C,D,E"` @QHarr

Comment: I'm quite grateful for the tip and not getting downvoted into hell btw, I realize the original post had no code and once I knew what to google, there is posts that could be marked duplicate, but generally are more specific vs this is a broader question.